# Inheriting methods with override-equivalent signatures

Tags: java

According to [jls-9.4.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1.3)

> If an interface I inherits a default method whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited by I, then a
>   compile-time error occurs. (This is the case whether the other method
>   is abstract or default.)

From above description following code should not compile.

However, when I compile this code, its working absolutely fine.

```
interface A {
    void foo(String s);
}

interface B<T> extends A {
    default void foo(T x) {
    }
}

interface C extends B<String> {
}
```

Why does it compile?

Answer (score 5):

> If an interface I inherits a default method whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited by I, then a compile-time error occurs. (This is the case whether the other method is abstract or default.)

The quote refers to the following situation:

```
interface A {
    void foo(String s);
}

interface B<T> {
    default void foo(T x) {
    }
}

interface C extends A, B<String> {        
}
```

where C both inherits a default method and another method with the same signature.

In your given situation `B#foo` already overrides `A#foo` and hence C only inherits a single method.